# How can i read/set atribut for object soap

Tags: delphi, soap, delphi-2010, indy10, webservices-client

If i use VB .NET follow code it work good. But How can i realize it on delphi 2010.
My problem is to find analog the r.MessageData.AppData.Any.

I try to use

```
rootNode := otv.MessageData.AppData.ObjectToSOAP(rootNode,rootNode,HttpRIO.Converter,'OrderInfo','otv',[],s);
  or p := otv.MessageData.AppData.DataContext.GetDataPointer(0);
```

But I cann't find atribut of object of AppData - (orderId for example).

I must to read and set atribut for appData - how can i do it on Delphi 2010

Thank you.

```
    **part of unit WSDL Importer(CommonAppDataType class is empty)**
unit AisMFCService;

interface

uses InvokeRegistry, SOAPHTTPClient, Types, XSBuiltIns;

const
  IS_OPTN = $0001;
  IS_UNBD = $0002;
  IS_NLBL = $0004;
  IS_ATTR = $0010;
  IS_REF  = $0080;


type

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // The following types, referred to in the WSDL document are not being represented
  // in this file. They are either aliases[@] of other types represented or were referred
  // to but never[!] declared in the document. The types from the latter category
  // typically map to predefined/known XML or Embarcadero types; however, they could also 
  // indicate incorrect WSDL documents that failed to declare or import a schema type.
  // ************************************************************************ //
  // !:string          - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:anyURI          - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:dateTime        - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]
  // !:base64Binary    - "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"[Gbl]

  Include              = class;                 { "http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"[GblCplx] }
  Include2             = class;                 { "http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"[GblElm] }
  orgExternalType      = class;                 { "http://eos.ru/doc/service"[GblCplx] }
  MessageType          = class;                 { "http://eos.ru/doc/service"[GblCplx] }
  SubMessageType       = class;                 { "http://eos.ru/doc/service"[GblCplx] }
  MessageDataTypeOfCommonAppDataType = class;   { "http://eos.ru/doc/service"[GblCplx] }
  CommonAppDataType    = class;                 { "http://eos.ru/doc/service"[GblCplx] }
  AppDocumentType      = class;                 { "http://eos.ru/doc/service"[GblCplx] }
  ReferenceType        = class;                 { "http://eos.ru/doc/service"[GblCplx] }
  Message_             = class;                 { "http://eos.ru/doc/service"[GblElm] }
  MessageData          = class;                 { "http://eos.ru/doc/service"[GblElm] }
  orgExternalType2     = class;                 { "http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315"[GblCplx] }
  MessageType2         = class;                 { "http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315"[GblCplx] }
  SubMessageType2      = class;                 { "http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315"[GblCplx] }
  MessageDataTypeOfCommonAppDataType2 = class;   { "http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315"[GblCplx] }
  CommonAppDataType2   = class;                 { "http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315"[GblCplx] }
  AppDocumentType2     = class;                 { "http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315"[GblCplx] }
  ReferenceType2       = class;                 { "http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315"[GblCplx] }
  Message_2            = class;                 { "http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315"[GblElm] }
  MessageData2         = class;                 { "http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315"[GblElm] }
  sendRequestMessage   = class;                 { "http://eos.ru/doc/Message"[Lit][GblElm] }
  ResponseMessage      = class;                 { "http://eos.ru/doc/Message"[Lit][GblElm] }
  sendGetStatusRequestMessage = class;          { "http://eos.ru/doc/Message"[Lit][GblElm] }
  GetStatusResponseMessage = class;             { "http://eos.ru/doc/Message"[Lit][GblElm] }
  SubMessage           = class;                 { "http://eos.ru/doc/service"[Alias] }
  SubMessage2          = class;                 { "http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315"[Alias] }
....

  // ************************************************************************ //
  // XML       : CommonAppDataType, global, <complexType> (AppDAta)
  // Namespace : http://eos.ru/doc/service
  // ************************************************************************ //
  CommonAppDataType = class(TRemotable)
  private
  published
  end;
```

### xml text from webService

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><ResponseMessage xmlns="http://eos.ru/doc/Message"><Message xmlns="http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315"><Sender><Code>342703391</Code><Name>Дело</Name></Sender><Recipient><Code>123456789</Code><Name>АИС МФЦ</Name></Recipient><Originator><Code>123456789</Code><Name>АИС МФЦ</Name></Originator><TypeCode>GSRV</TypeCode><Status>ACCEPT</Status><Date>2013-08-07T16:19:26.39125+04:00</Date><ExchangeType>0</ExchangeType></Message><MessageData xmlns="http://smev.gosuslugi.ru/rev120315"><AppData><OrderInfo xmlns=""><orderId>10028894</orderId><statusCode>1</statusCode><comment>Заявление передано в информационную систему "Дело"</comment></OrderInfo></AppData></MessageData></ResponseMessage></s:Body></s:Envelope>
```

---

VB.NEt  code (its work)

```
Dim a As New ais.AisMFCRequestMessage
        Dim doc As New Xml.XmlDocument
        Dim el As Xml.XmlElement
        el = doc.CreateElement("GetStatuesRequest")
        el.InnerXml = TextBox1.Text
        MsgBox(el.InnerXml)
        Dim els() As Xml.XmlElement
        Dim s As ais.IAisMFCService

        s = New ais.AisMFCServiceClient
        a.Message = New ais.MessageType
        a.Message.Sender = New ais.orgExternalType
        a.Message.Sender.Code = "123456789"
        a.Message.Sender.Name = "АИС МФЦ"
        a.Message.Recipient = New ais.orgExternalType
        a.Message.Recipient.Code = "1234567890"
        a.Message.Recipient.Name = "Delo"
        a.Message.Originator = New ais.orgExternalType
        a.Message.Originator.Code = "123456789"
        a.Message.Originator.Name = "АИС МФЦ"
        a.Message.ServiceName = "SN1"
        a.Message.TypeCode = ais.TypeCodeEnum.GSRV
        a.Message.Status = ais.StatusEnum.REQUEST
        a.Message.Date = Now.Date
        a.Message.ExchangeType = ais.ExchangeTypeEnum.Item2
        a.Message.ServiceCode = "01"
        a.Message.CaseNumber = "1"
        a.MessageData = New ais.MessageDataTypeOfCommonAppDataType
        a.MessageData.AppData = New ais.CommonAppDataType
        ReDim els(0)
        els(0) = el
        a.MessageData.AppData.Any = els

        Dim r As ais.AisMFCResponseMessage = s.CreateRequest(a)
        MsgBox(r.Message.Date.ToString)

        Dim m = r.MessageData.AppData.Any.ToArray
        For Each o In m
            el = o
            TextBox1.Text = el.InnerXml
        Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set the correct options on Delphi's WSDL Importer, so the imported class doesn't contain the data you're looking for. The WSDL importer is rather fussy and it can take some trial and error to get the expected results. In many cases, I've given up and done it manually.

Comment: if I do it on VB.NET, the problem is same(i don't see these parametrs). But I can read from r.MessageData.AppData.Any.ToArray. where .Any is a property of VB.Net. I think to find this property in Delphi 2010 too.

Comment: As I already explained, the Delphi 2010 WSDL importer is very fussy. I don't know how VB.NET does it. Your question asked why you couldn't access properties in Delphi, and I said you need to experiment with the import options in the WSDL importer. Have you tried different import options?